# Select with images - ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, select, drop-down-menu, icons

instead of textfields, i would like to create a select field or dropdown with images.

So basically something like that:
http://www.designtickle.com/cdnmedia/-/2012/12/dropdown-navigation-web-ui/04-pink-online-store-dropdown-nav.png

I read that ms-dropdown can be used for this in ruby on rails, but didnt find any tutorials or code samples how to actually do it. Any help with this apreciated.

Comment: I think it is not rails question. It is more `css` and `javascript` question. You need to find some well documented `css` libs which has adequate documentation. Twitter bootstrap for example or materialize.css